# How do I extract the name from pg_timezone_names()?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres I am trying to extract the name from `pg_timezone_names()` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html). Right now, it is returning all the records in 1 column.

The version of Postgres is 8.0.2, and the below image is what `select pg_timezone_names()` returns:

[image]

Comment: its either postgres or redshift - not the same thing. please remove 1 tag.

Comment: Are you **really** still using Postgres 8.0?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A lot of people use abandonware. People are still posting questions about Hibernate 3.x and that branch has been dead since 2011. Current version is 5.2.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, it's the version I have to use.

Answer (score 3):

After spinning my wheels on this for quite some time, I figured out how to make this work on Redshift (which is based off an old version of Postgres).

When you use just `select pg_timezone_names()` it returns a composite row record:

```
> select top 5 pg_timezone_names()

pg_timezone_names                         
------------------------------------------
(Antarctica/Macquarie,+11,11:00:00,f)     
(Antarctica/McMurdo,NZST,12:00:00,f)      
(Antarctica/Davis,+07,07:00:00,f)         
(Antarctica/Rothera,-03,-03:00:00,f)      
(Antarctica/DumontDUrville,+10,10:00:00,f)
```

However, we need to break down the composite record into separate columns before we can make use of them individually. This can be done like so:

```
> select top 5
  tz.name,
  tz.abbrev,
  tz.utc_offset,
  tz.is_dst
from pg_timezone_names() tz(name text, abbrev text, utc_offset interval, is_dst boolean);

name                      | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
--------------------------+--------+------------+-------
Antarctica/Macquarie      | +11    | 11:00:00   | false 
Antarctica/McMurdo        | NZST   | 12:00:00   | false 
Antarctica/Davis          | +07    | 07:00:00   | false 
Antarctica/Rothera        | -03    | -03:00:00  | false 
Antarctica/DumontDUrville | +10    | 10:00:00   | false
```

Comment: Is there any documentation or a name to search with for this method? I'm not familiar with it and I would like to know more about how you expanded the composite record.

Answer (score 2):

Atleast on Postgres 10+, there is a pg_timezone_names view that can be used for this.
Simply use either of the below queries:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names;
```

or

```
select name from pg_timezone_names
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t=# \sf pg_timezone_names()
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names(OUT name text, OUT abbrev text, OUT utc_offset interval, OUT is_dst boolean)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE internal
 STABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS $function$pg_timezone_names$function$
```

so `pg_timezone_names()` is a function that returns a SETOF. This is why you see the whole row as one column, try:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names()
```

or in case of super old version maybe:

```
select * from pg_timezone_names() as t(name,abbrev,utc_offset,is_dest)
```

Comment: When I run `select * from pg_timezone_names()`, I get `ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`.

Comment: I still got the same error :(, the best hack solution we decided on is just to create a new table.

Comment: Yes, the same column definition error occurred. We decided to just grab the timezone names from the docs, and create a new table with the name as a single column.

Comment: @Kelli-Jean I figured out how to make it work, see my response below.

Comment: `select * from pg_timezone_names();` works fine for me in `psql (PostgreSQL) 14.7 (Ubuntu 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)`